# Completion warning in glht

Tags: r, mixed-model, convergence, post-hoc

I am running a sequence of post-hoc tests with `glht` (`mutcomp` package), but the function summary warns me that the algorithm ends with an `error > abseps` as in:

```
> hr.ph <- glht(hr.lm, linfct = ph_conditional);
> summary(hr.ph)

Warning messages:
In RET$pfunction("adjusted", ...) : Completion with error > abseps
```

Does anybody know what that means? I think it is a matter of modifying the parameters of the algorithm that summary runs. Looking at the documentation, I could not find a way of actually doing so. Do you have any suggestion? Also, how does one know the default values of these algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning thrown from `mvtnorm::pmvnorm`. It can in some cases be avoided by adjusting `maxpts` from the default 25000, such as:

```r
summary(hr.ph, test = adjusted(maxpts = 10*25000))
```